# Cannot execute commands on Windows server over SSH session with Plink

Tags: ssh, plink

I am trying to use Plink for running commands on remote server. Both, local & remote machine are Windows. Though I am able to connect to the remote machine using Plink, i am not able to use the '-m file' option. I tried the following three ways but to no avail:

Try 1:

```
plink.exe -ssh -pw mypwd john.doe@server -m file.txt
```

Output:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/john.doe: No such file or directory
dir: not found
```

'file.txt' only contains one command i.e., dir

Try 2:

```
plink.exe -ssh -pw mypwd john.doe@server dir
```

Output:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/john.doe: No such file or directory
dir: not found
```

Try 3:

```
plink.exe -ssh -pw mypwd john.doe@server < file.txt
```

In this case, I get the following output:

```
Using username "john.doe".

                            ****USAGE WARNING****

This is a private computer system. This computer system, including all
..... including personal information, placed or sent over this system
may be monitored.

Use of this computer system, authorized or unauthorized, constitutes consent
... constitutes consent to monitoring for these purposes.


dirCould not chdir to home directory /home/john.doe: No such file or directory
Microsoft Windows [Version x.x.xxx]
(C) Copyright 1985-2003 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Program Files\OpenSSH>
```

After I get the above prompt, it hangs. Any help in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

This is working now.

`plink -ssh -pw xxx john.doe@server cmd.exe /c move c://sample//jd//file.txt c://test//`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `plink -m` is working fine: the commands from file.txt are being sent to the server.

However, your SSH server is running a shell (probably `bash` because OpenSSH for Windows uses Cygwin) that does not understand the commands you are using, like `move` and `dir`. Because `bash` implements its own versions of those commands (`mv` and `ls`, respectively). As you discovered, you need to run `cmd.exe /C` out of the Windows directory for your SSH server to correctly interpret the meaning of your commands. The other option is to use the `bash` versions of the commands directly.

Answer (score 1):

You are using OpenSSH over Cygwin on your Windows server.

The Cygwin emulates Unix environment on Windows.

So you have to use Unix, not Windows commands (e.g. `mv` not `move` or `rename`)

And you need to use Unix-like paths, not Windows paths (forward slashes in particular).

Moreover, your server seems wrongly configured.

---

> Could not chdir to home directory /home/john.doe: No such file or directory

This is likely an incorrectly configured account. The error is not related to the commands you are executing.